# Android - Использование Timer в ViewPager

Tags: java, android

### Возможно ли использовать Timer в VievPager?

Чтобы немного облегчить понимание вопроса, объясню: в приложении нужно добиться того, чтобы была возможность листать "страницы", где на одной из них, выборочно, изменяется, раз в секунду, текст (в данном случае идёт время).

Перелистывание "страниц" было решено осуществить с помощью VievPager

Первоначальный код делал как по образцам в интернете:

**1)** В MainActivity поместил код для адаптера

```
ViewPager pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
                pager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
                pager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

**2)** В MyAdapter поместил код определяющий количество страниц (их 3) и образование фрагментов (если не ошибаюсь)

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager mgr) {
        super(mgr);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {return(3);} //Колличество страниц (3)
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) { //getItem создаёт новую страницу
        return(PageFragment.newInstance(position));
    }
}
```

**3)** А уже в PageFragmen поместил остальной код, который, нужно заметить, без таймера работает идеально. Проблема находится именно в TimerTask.

Во время расписывания TimerTask, мне нужно, чтобы TextView ежесекундно обновлялся. Для этого, после действия таймера, я использую строчку:

```
...

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { //Для оновления данных
                        @Override
                        public void run() { 

...
```

Запустить программу мне никак не даёт выделение красным "runOnUiThread", наведя на него появляется надпись:

> Cannot resolve method 'runOnUiThread(anonymous java.lang.Runnable)'

Надеюсь, изложил понятно. Рассчитываю на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`runOnUiThread` это метод Activity. Чтобы использовать его во фрагменте, пишите так:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { //Для оновления данных
        @Override
        public void run() { 
            ...
        }
});
```